# Computed property in controller based on route's model in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to implement computed property in controller that changes when data in route's model changed.

Route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return new Ember.RSVP.hash({
            ingredients: this.store.findAll('ingredient'),
            recipes: this.store.peekAll('recipe')
        });
    },

    setupController: function(controller, modelHash) {
        controller.setProperties(modelHash);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    pageNumber: 0,
    pageSize: 16,

    pages: function() {
        var pages = [];
        if (this.model != null) {
            var content = this.model.recipes;
            while (content.length > 0) {
                pages.push(content.splice(0, this.get("pageSize")));
            }
        }
        return pages;
    }.property('model.recipes.@each', 'pageSize'), 

    recipesOnPage: function() {
        return this.get('pages')[this.get('pageNumber')];
    }.property('pages', 'pageNumber')
});
```

This code produce no error, but doesn't work - "pages" always empty. And "pages" property doesn't recomputed on model changing. What am I doing wrong? And how to achieve desired result?

P.S. Ember version - 1.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have modified `setupController` hook, your `controller` has properties `ingredients` and `recipes`, but has no `model` property.

So your computed property should be:

```
pages: function() {
 // avoid using model here
 // use this.get('recipes') instead of this.model.recipes
}.property('recipes.[]', 'pageSize')
```

SetupController hook [guides link](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/routing/setting-up-a-controller/).

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, now I have problem with "recipes", cause it PromiseArray, but that is another problem =).

Comment: promices are resolved (or rejected) in `model` hook, so in controller `recipes` is Ember.Array

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    pageNumber: 0,
    pageSize: 16,

    pages: function() {
        var pages = [];
        var model = this.get('model');
        if (model != null) {
            var content = model.get('recipes');
            while (content.length > 0) {
                pages.push(content.splice(0, this.get("pageSize")));
            }
        }
        return pages;
    }.property('model.recipes.@each', 'pageSize'), 

    recipesOnPage: function() {
        return this.get('pages')[this.get('pageNumber')];
    }.property('pages', 'pageNumber')
});
```